# Define width in percentage on relative positioned `<a>` list

Tags: html, css

I've a navigation with bunch of `<a>` links:

```
<section class="nav">
    <nav>
        <a href="#" data-hover="BLA">BLA</a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="BLA">BLA</a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="BLA">BLA</a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="BLA">BLA</a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="BLA">BLA</a>
    </nav>
</section>
```

My target is to cover the whole display with these links. So each link needs a height of `20%`.

My problem is now, the `<section>` have a `position:fixed` and the height set to `100%`.
How can I set the height to `20%` with the `position:relative`?

Here are the additional CSS statements and at the end a demo fiddle.

```
.container,
.container > section, /* the part where the section tag above will set to 100% */
.container > section > article{
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav{
    z-index: 1000;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.nav nav a{
    display: block;
    height: 20%; /* the 20% which doesn't work because of the position:relative;
    background: blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rhEHl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `height: 20%` on your `a` elements sets them to 20% height of their containing element. In this case the containing element is your `nav`, which doesn't have any height specified by you and defaults to the height of its content. You need to set your `nav` to 100% height to fill the `section`:

```css
.nav nav {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**Working CodePen demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hdIuC).